# Override a custom documentclass to put all page numbers at the bottom

Tags: page-numbering, document-classes, thesis

I am using a documentclass provided by my school to write my thesis. I realize this question may not have an answer without my being able to understand what is written in that file but let me try anyway.

Pages at the beginning of chapters are numbered at the bottom, but other pages are numbered in the top right corner. These other pages also have the title of the chapter centered at the top of every page. The problem is that sometimes my chapter title runs into the page number, sometimes even overlapping.

I would like to put the page number at the bottom instead. Since I'm hoping not to mess with the documentclass file, I'd like to do this by over-riding the settings from there.

From reading other posts, I tried to do this:

```
\documentclass[
    12pt,oneside]{myschool_PhD}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

Nope.

\end{document}
```

This does put the page numbers at the bottom but it also puts a wide margin and horizontal line at the top of every page. From the look of it I probably have to pick which "pagestyle" is active, not try to write both. But... how to I get all my page numbers at the bottom without changing anything else?

Comment: If you should use `\pagestyle{headings}`, using `fancy` is far away from the specifications than using `plain`.

Comment: Okay, actually, let me put the question back how it was and accept your answer, then ask another one. This is getting messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And the simple way is

```
  \pagestyle{plain}
```

instead of your

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

Comment: Simple is best. I realize now there's another issue though. Let me edit my post accordingly.

Comment: @j0equ1nn It is better to ask new question, because this one may be useful for future users.

Comment: Woops. I saw your comment after editing it.